# Import .accdb file into Stata (Mac)

Tags: macos, ms-access, odbc, stata

I'm looking to import a Microsoft Access file (.accdb) into Stata to read and analyze the data.

The trouble is I'm operating on a Mac, which doesn't support Microsoft Access.

I've tried transferring the Microsoft Access data into Excel, then saving as a .csv.  This allowed me to open the data in Stata, however, it's imperative that I alter the data from its original source as little as possible.

Ideally, I'd like to import the .accdb file directly into Stata.  To do this I believe I'll need to run an odbc driver/command, but haven't had any luck yet.  Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: Aren't there MA ODBC drivers for Mac?

Comment: Yes, I've tried using Actual Tech ODBC driver for MA for Mac.  I've configured the ODBC using ODBC Manager, yet when I try to import the database into Stata I see the message "ODBC data sources have not been configured"

Comment: That sounds like an ODBC problem rather than a Stata one. I would try to see if there's a way to test the connection through ODBC manager or some sort of command line tool that comes bundled with the drivers. Once that works, I would start on trying in Stata. Also, you might consider adding the output of `odbc list` and your code for loading the data to the question. Also, you might try this also on Statalist (but note the policy on cross-posting in the FAQ). Also try tweaking the odbcmgr settings.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I was able to sort it out eventually.

Comment: The problem was with the ODBC Manager itself.  It seems to have taken a restart, and submission of the DSN under User DSN instead of System DSN.  From then on, Stata was able to recognize the driver.

Comment: You ought to write it up as a solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ODBC Manager itself.  It seems to have taken a restart, and submission of the DSN under User DSN instead of System DSN.  From then on, Stata was able to recognize the driver.